# Calculating average for certain time period in every year

Tags: r, time-series, average

I need to calculate seasonal averages for my data every year, the calculation of average is not in the same calendar year. I have defined season by date and am looking to calculate average temperature, precipitation etc for that time period every year (eg `12/21/1981` to `02/15/1982` , `12/21/1982` to `02/15/1983`) and so on.

Is there an efficient way of doing this in R?

Below is my data:

```
library(xts)
seq <- timeBasedSeq('1981-01-01/1985-06-30') 
Data <- xts(1:length(seq),seq)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give the desired output (for a small section of your data)? Is the column called `[, 1]` in the data provided the precipitation? Do you need a way using the `xts` package, or is that just what you are using to get the sample data?

Comment: You are not making it easy to help you... can you include IN YOUR QUESTION an example output (eg a table) with example data (another table) showing how you want things to be transformed? Your data you have included doesn't look like it contains enough info about precipitation/temperature. Also, why are you using `xts`?

Comment: My desired output is the average value of the variable for each season / year.
I have used xts only to get the sample data here, I am looking for any package to calculate the average.
As far as I have explored, lubridate and xts can be used calculate average by month or by weeks but I have not found a way to do average by selected dates, that exist in two calendar years.

Comment: My apologies, I will edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we push the time forward by 11 days then the dates we want are those at or before February 26th so let `tt` be such a date vector and `ok` be a logical vector which is TRUE if the corresponding `tt` element is at or before Febrary 26th.  Finally aggregate `Data[ok]` by end of period year.

```
tt <- time(Data) + 11
ok <- format(tt, "%m-%d") < "02-26"
aggregate(Data[ok], as.integer(as.yearmon(tt))[ok], mean)
```

giving:

```
1981   23.0
1982  382.5
1983  747.5
1984 1112.5
1985 1478.5
```

If you want to do it without xts then assume our input is `DF` try this:

```
DF <- fortify.zoo(Data) # input

tt <- DF[, 1] + 11
ok <- format(tt, "%m-%d") < "02-26"
year <- as.numeric(format(tt, "%Y"))
aggregate(DF[ok, -1, drop = FALSE], list(year = year[ok]), mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a data-frame centered approach using tidyverse grammar (which could be translated to base R, if you prefer):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_in <- tibble(
    date = seq(as.Date('1981-01-01'), as.Date('1985-06-30'), by = 'day'), 
    x = seq_along(date)
)

str(df_in)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    1642 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ date: Date, format: "1981-01-01" "1981-01-02" ...
#>  $ x   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

df_out <- df_in %>% 
    # reformat data to keep months and days, but use identical year, so...
    mutate(same_year = as.Date(format(date, '1970-%m-%d'))) %>% 
    # ...we can subset to rows we care about with simpler logic
    filter(same_year < as.Date('1970-02-15') | same_year > as.Date('1970-12-21')) %>% 
    # shift so all in one year and use for grouping
    group_by(run = as.integer(format(date - 60, '%Y'))) %>% 
    summarise(    # aggregate each gruop
        start_date = min(date), 
        end_date = max(date), 
        mean_x = mean(x)
    )

df_out
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>     run start_date end_date   mean_x
#>   <int> <date>     <date>      <dbl>
#> 1  1980 1981-01-01 1981-02-14     23
#> 2  1981 1981-12-22 1982-02-14    383
#> 3  1982 1982-12-22 1983-02-14    748
#> 4  1983 1983-12-22 1984-02-14   1113
#> 5  1984 1984-12-22 1985-02-14   1479
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Can you please explain what the ' -60' does in the group_by function? Does it subtract 60 days from the same year as defined in previous steps?

Comment: Yep, it shifts all the dates back by 60 days so each run is in one year. The `format(..., '%Y')` extracts that year, which can then be used for grouping runs.